# Can I create a class which can be unpacked?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

For example:

```
x = (1, 2)
a,b = x
```

Now I'd like to accomplish this in the case of `x` being an instance of some class that isn't a list or tuple. Simply overriding `__getitem__` or `__getslice__` doesn't work:

```
class Test(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return 1

a,b = Test()
```

results in a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. Can I make this work without inheriting from `list` or `tuple` (or their respective `UserX` classes)? Or is this just some under-the-hood magic that I cannot use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override `__iter__` or `__getitem__`. Here's an example using `__iter__`:

```
class Test(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([1, 2])

a,b = Test()
```

Be careful, `__iter__` needs to return an iterator. The easiest way to do this is to either wrap your data structure in `iter`, or have it yield from a generator.

For an example of using `__getitem__`, see jonrsharpe's excellent answer.

Comment: You don't *need* to, but it's probably neater!

Answer (score 4):

Per [PEP-234](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/), which defines iterators (emphasis mine):

> An object can be iterated over with "for" if it implements
>   `__iter__()` **or `__getitem__()`**.

You *can* do this with `__getitem__`, but it has to throw an `IndexError` to indicate when you've reached the end. You see `too many values to unpack` because there is no way for Python to tell that it's finished iterating over your object.

This would work:

```
class Test(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key > 1:
            raise IndexError
        return 1
```

In use:

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> a, b = t
>>> a
1
>>> b
1
>>> t[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __getitem__
IndexError
```

Comment: Oh, good to know! I would not have assumed that `__getitem__` would work for this.

Comment: I thought about implementing `__len__`, but I was wrong. Well, I guess it's easier to ask forgiveness :) .

Comment: I'd accept this answer as well if I could. Thank you kindly!